# Detection clang on different platforms

Tags: regex, cmake, micro-optimization

Faced with the problem of parsing version of clang for different vendors `clang --version|head -1`

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn) => 3.5
FreeBSD clang version 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032) 20140512 => 3.4.1
clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/rc2) => 3.5.0
```

Now have this regular expression

```
match: (clang version|based on LLVM)\ (\d+)(\.\d+)(\.\d+)?
to \2\3\4
```

I need to exclude `(clang version|based on LLVM)` from the result match() - `\1`.

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question looks like you're expecting CMake's regex handling to be Perl-like, but it's pretty different.

In CMake syntax, the following should do what you want:

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
  execute_process(COMMAND clang --version COMMAND head -1 OUTPUT_VARIABLE ClangVersionLine)
  string(REGEX MATCH "(clang version|based on LLVM) ([0-9]\\.[0-9]\\.?[0-9]?)" UnusedVar "${ClangVersionLine}")
  set(ClangVersion "${CMAKE_MATCH_2}")
  message("ClangVersion - ${ClangVersion}")
endif()
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since the tool you use is based on PCRE, this pattern should work:

```
(?m)(?:^Apple .*)?\K \d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}
```

The `(?m)` is not useful in real life because you only test one line, so you can remove it.

The `\K` removes all that have been matched on the left from the match result.

If you use another language/tool where the `\K` feature is not available you can use a capturing group to extract the information you want from the whole match result:

```
(?:^Apple .*)? ([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+){1,2})
```

With cmake:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "(^Apple .*)? ([0-9]+([.][0-9]+){1,2}).*" "\\2" CLANG_VERSION "${_clang_version_info}")
```

Comment: cmake: Invalid escape sequence \b `string(REGEX REPLACE "(?m)(?:^Apple\b.*)?\K\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}" "\\1\\2" CLANG_VERSION "${_clang_version_info}")`

Comment: if you remove the `\K` do you have always the same message?

Comment: Looks like you're using CMake's regex handling, not PCRE?

Comment: cmake does not support PCRE, only the bare regex also scolds to use `\b` -> `??` | `\d` -> `[0-9]` | `\.` -> `.` | `\D` -> `??`